# PostgreSQL from NodeJS application

Tags: windows, node.js, postgresql, ado.net

I am exploring how best to access a PostgreSQL/PostGIS DB from NodeJS. All I need is simple SQL SELECT queries. Nothing more complex than:

```
SELECT * 
FROM portal.catalog AS cat 
WHERE ST_Intersects(st_geogfromtext('SRID=4326;POLYGON((20 50 ,19 50,19 49,20 50 ))'), cat.gpoly) 
LIMIT 5000;
```

This will be on a windows7 or windows2008 server, running PostgreSQL 9.2/PostGIS 2.0, The traffic will be pretty light (only a few requests per minute).

Some preliminary research I have done has come up with the following potential directions. But I was interested in hearing from others what is working for them (as an easy implementation).

1. https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres (But I am having trouble building it do to firewall issues), Supposed the "pure" solution is better, but I am having issues there also) https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres-pure
2. http://www.infoq.com/articles/the_edge_of_net_and_node (And then I guess I would write my own ADO.NET adapter to PostgreSQL)
3. I have also seen references to ODBC for NodeJS (unclear if this is the way to go)
4. Is there something like the SQL adapter for NodeJS? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2012/06/08/introducing-the-microsoft-driver-for-node-js-for-sql-server.aspx
5. There was also a full blown ORM by EntitySpaces (which went bankrupt). Now a defunct opensource project: https://github.com/EntitySpaces/entityspaces.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got BrianC's PostgresPure system working (must have been a dependent module malfunctioning, since I did not do anything special.

Works just great.

See: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres-pure

Answer (score 0):

I've used node-postgres in the past, but recently opted for [any-db](https://github.com/grncdr/node-any-db), which has support for PostgreSQL.

Both have worked well, although I prefer any-db, particularly with respect to pooling and transactions. I believe any-db deserves more recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Any-db is layered on top of BrianC's node-postgres.

But I just got the https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres-pure working, and it is a pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

EntitySpaces is the way to go, not defunct at all.

http://download.cnet.com/EntitySpaces-Studio/3000-10250_4-10590953.html?tag=mncol;1